# concatenating scraped data in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

how can I concatenate data such so that my code would be like US-NJ-Camden:

```
def parse_items(self, response):
     hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
     loc_Con = hxs.select('/tr/td[2]/span/span/span') #for country
     loc_Reg = hxs.select('/tr/td[2]/span/span') #for region
     loc_Loc = hxs.select('//tr[3]/td[2]/span/span') #for local
     items = []
     for titles in titles:
     item = somethingItem()
     item ["country"] = loc_Con.select('text()').extract()
     item ["region"] = loc_Reg.select('text()').extract()
     item ["location"] = loc_Loc.select('text()').extract()
     item ["code"] = #["country"]-item ["region"]-item ["location"] like the above example
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `format()` this way:

```
item["code"] = "{}-{}-{}".format(item["country"], item["region"], item["location"])
```

or this way:

```
item["code"] = "{country}-{region}-{location}".format(country=item["country"], 
                                                      region=item["region"],
                                                      location=item["location"])
```

or an old-style formatting:

```
item["code"] = "%s-%s-%s" % (item["country"], item["region"], item["location"])
```

UPD:

And, don't forget to get the 0th items from the extracted lists:

```
item ["country"] = loc_Con.select('text()').extract()
item ["region"] = loc_Reg.select('text()').extract()
item ["location"] = loc_Loc.select('text()').extract()

item ["country"] = item ["country"][0] if item ["country"] else ""
item ["region"] = item ["region"][0] if item ["region"] else ""
item ["location"] = item ["location"][0] if item ["location"] else ""
```

Comment: what if I want to append only item["code"] to my csv, how should i write it?

Comment: @chano then don't define `country`, `region` and `location` inside an item, just `code`.

Comment: will it run without country =Field() like this in the item?

Comment: yup, and, btw, if you don't need these fields - remove them from the `somethingItem` class.

Comment: the tried the format and it works, but when i checked the csv file, i see that the result for code gave me [u'US']-[u'NJ']-[u'Camden']

Comment: @chano this means that country, region and location are optional and may not exist on the page. Please see updated answer.

Comment: it gave me exceptions.KeyError: 'country'

Comment: oh, i forgot to type something in there and btw, it works! thanks